# Can't run flutter app with firebase on IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, dart, flutter

I get this error when I try running.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Starting Xcode build...

Xcode build done.                                           35.9s

*** First throw call stack:

(

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001099ff1bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108f9d735 objc_exception_throw + 48

2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001099ff015 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197

3   Runner                              0x00000001040a8aa0 +[FIRApp configure] + 576

4   Runner                              0x00000001044a931c -[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin init] + 188

5   Runner                              0x00000001044a91c9 +[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 297

6   Runner                              0x000000010404d19e +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 126

7   Runner                        <…>
```

[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.1.5, on Mac OS X 10.14.2 18C54, locale en-NG)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.1.6)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

Comment: how is your ios/Runner folder ? did you put info.list ?

Comment: You mean info.plist?? Yes. no info.list tho

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I guess you forgot to add `GoogleService-Info.plist` file to your ios project

Follow this [codelab (point 6 and 7 specifically)](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/index.html?index=..%2F..index#6) for detailed instruction.

Remember that it's not enough to copy it in your `ios/Runner` folder from the `finder/explorer` or `command line`.

**You need to open the `ios/Runner.xcworkspace` with `Xcode` and add the file to the *project tree***. **Xcode needs to be aware of this file, so that it can be copied in the application bundle**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my mistake was I copied it directly inside the top level runner directory.  Putting it inside the Runner/Runner directory solved my issue.

Comment: Indeed this is exactly the issue I've been struggling with. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this one too ! it made me crazy

Comment: Thanks for this!

Answer (score 3):

For cases with **two** google-services plist files you can add a new build phase to copy the file to the correct location on compilation.

1. Create a config folder on the root of the iOS folder and inside it
   have the names of the two apps/builds you're targeting. Add the
   files accordingly to the folders. Next, head to Target Runner and on
   the Build Phases section.
2. Add a **new run script phase** by clicking the + button at the top
   of that section.
3. Rename it to a descriptive title, I call mine **Copy
   GoogleServices-Info.plist to correct location** Then move it right
   below the Link Binary With Libraries phase.
4. Copy the following script into the build phase body

```
environment="default"
# Regex to extract the scheme name from the Build Configuration
# We have named our Build Configurations as Debug-dev, Debug-prod etc.
# Here, dev and prod are the scheme names. This kind of naming is required by Flutter for flavors to work.
# We are using the $CONFIGURATION variable available in the XCode build environment to extract 
# the environment (or flavor)
# For eg.
# If CONFIGURATION="Debug-prod", then environment will get set to "prod".
if [[ $CONFIGURATION =~ -([^-]*)$ ]]; then
environment=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi

echo $environment

# Name and path of the resource we're copying
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST=GoogleService-Info.plist
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE=${PROJECT_DIR}/config/${environment}/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}

# Make sure GoogleService-Info.plist exists
echo "Looking for ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} in ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE}"
if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE ]
then
echo "No GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper directory."
exit 1
fi

# Get a reference to the destination location for the GoogleService-Info.plist
# This is the default location where Firebase init code expects to find GoogleServices-Info.plist file
PLIST_DESTINATION=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app
echo "Will copy ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST} to final destination: ${PLIST_DESTINATION}"

# Copy over the prod GoogleService-Info.plist for Release builds
cp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE}" "${PLIST_DESTINATION}"
```

Try running the app and it should be good

Answer (score 0):

**Setup firebase as in official documentation and then follow the follwoing steps for running on emulators:**

**For Android setup**:

In android/app/build.gradle:

```
 android {                                                                                     
   defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }                                                                                      
 }
```

```
 android {                                                                                     
   compileSdkVersion 33                                                                                      
 }
```

In android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
      dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}
```

**For iOS setup:**

In iOS podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '15.0' "
```

In terminal open root directory of your project and do:

```
cd ios
rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock
pod cache clean --all
pod install --repo-update
pod install
```

Now finally run on iOS simulator (pod install and XCode build will take a lot of time in 1st run for an app)

*Note Firebase CLI and Flutter SDK should be latest updated as of June, 2023